# How add class='active' to html menu with php

Tags: php

I want to put my html navigation in a separate php file so when I need to edit it, I only have to edit it once. The problem starts when I want to add the class active to the active page.

I've got three pages and one common file.

***common.php :***

```
<?php 
$nav = <<<EOD
   <div id="nav">
        <ul>
           <li><a <? if($page == 'one'): ?> class="active"<? endif ?> href="index.php">Tab1</a>/</li>
           <li><a href="two.php">Tab2</a></li>
           <li><a href="three.php">Tab3</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
EOD;
?>
```

***index.php :*** 
All three pages are identical except their $page is different on each page.

```
  <?php
     $page = 'one';      
     require_once('common.php');
    ?>
    <html>
       <head></head>
       <body>
          <?php echo $nav; ?>
       </body>
    </html>
```

This simply won't work unless I put my nav on each page, but then the whole purpose of separating the nav from all pages is ruined.

Is what I want to accomplish even possible? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: When doing this, the php code inside the li don't seem to run, it's just being printed as if it was html

Comment: First, PHP gets not parsed in heredoc strings (only variables) and second, the closing identifier (i.e. EOD) must be at the beginning of the line.

Comment: yes sorry I know that, thought it would be easier to read it like that.
the EOD is at the beginning of the line in my code, thats not the problem.

My problem is that it prints exactly what is in the EOD, also the php.

Comment: the reason is printing the php is because of a syntax error: <? if($page == 'one'): ?> should be <?php if($page == 'one'): ?>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your index.php code is correct.  I am including the updated code for common.php below then I will explain the differences.

```
<?php 
     $class = ($page == 'one') ? 'class="active"' : '';
     $nav = <<<EOD
        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
               <li><a $class href="index.php">Tab1</a>/</li>
               <li><a href="two.php">Tab2</a></li>
               <li><a href="three.php">Tab3</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>
 EOD;
 ?>
```

The first issue is that you need to make sure that the end declaration for your heredoc -- `EOD;` -- is not indented at all.  If it is indented, then you will get errors.

As for your issue with the PHP code not running within the heredoc statement, that is because you are looking at it wrong.  Using a heredoc statement is not the same as closing the PHP tags.  As such, you do not need to try reopening them.  That will do nothing for you.  The way the heredoc syntax works is that everything between the opening and closing is displayed exactly as written with the exception of variables.  Those are replaced with the associated value.  I removed your logic from the heredoc and used a tertiary function to determine the class to make this easier to see (though I don't believe any logical statements will work within the heredoc anyway)

To understand the heredoc syntax, it is the same as including it within double quotes ("), but without the need for escaping.  So your code could also be written like this:

```
<?php 
     $class = ($page == 'one') ? 'class="active"' : '';
     $nav = "<div id=\"nav\">
            <ul>
               <li><a $class href=\"index.php\">Tab1</a>/</li>
               <li><a href=\"two.php\">Tab2</a></li>
               <li><a href=\"three.php\">Tab3</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>";
 ?>
```

It will do exactly the same thing, just is written somewhat differently.  Another difference between heredoc and the string is that you can escape out of the string in the middle where you can't in the heredoc.  Using this logic, you can produce the following code:

```
<?php 
     $nav = "<div id=\"nav\">
            <ul>
               <li><a ".(($page == 'one') ? 'class="active"' : '')." href=\"index.php\">Tab1</a>/</li>
               <li><a href=\"two.php\">Tab2</a></li>
               <li><a href=\"three.php\">Tab3</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>";
 ?>
```

Then you can include the logic directly in the string like you originally intended.

Whichever method you choose makes very little (if any) difference in the performance of the script.  It mostly boils down to preference.  Either way, you need to make sure you understand how each works.

Comment: so, what is best, make a new file nav.php like Toader Mihai Claudiu suggested, or simply use ".(($page == 'one') ? 'class="active"' : '')." in the string ? 

since both ways work..

Answer (score 27):

why don't you do it like this:

in the pages:

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
      <?php $page = 'one'; include('navigation.php'); ?>
   </body>
</html>
```

in the navigation.php

```
<div id="nav">
   <ul>
      <li>
          <a <?php echo ($page == 'one') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> 
                 href="index1.php">Tab1</a>/</li>
      <li>
          <a <?php echo ($page == 'two') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> 
                  href="index2.php">Tab2</a>/</li>
      <li>
          <a <?php echo ($page == 'three') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> 
                  href="index3.php">Tab3</a>/</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

You will actually be able to control where in the page you are putting the navigation and what parameters you are passing to it.

Later edit: fixed syntax error.

Comment: Comparing your code and his (which while there is an issue with his use of the heredoc syntax works just fine), I would prefer to come into code looking at his.  Variables are declared at the top of the page, and the variables are used to place the navigation.  Simple formatting issue, but personal preference.  In any case, while your answer is good, it does not address the question asked.

Comment: i changed it to <?php echo ($page == 'one') ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> and it totally worked! THANKS you rock!

Comment: There is a principle that i come to cherish since i started to do programming. It's called the locality of information. Basically you would prefer to have all the information required to reason about some code near itself. this allow you to be able to decide locally about the purpose of some piece of code and force you to go in n places to gather that information.

Comment: @Joseph: Normally i would have written the following: <?php $page = 'one'; include('navigation.php'); ?> something like this: <?php echo navigation(array('page' => 'one')); ?> but it would have been more involved to exemplify easily.

Comment: so, is it to prefer to make a whole new nav.php file, or would you rather do like joseph suggested, simply use ".(($page == 'one') ? 'class="active"' : '')." in the string ?

Comment: @meow: According to your original post, you already had a separate nav file called common.php.  Whether you use Toader's recommendation on how to format the code or mine makes no difference.  You will end up with the same result.  It is all personal preference really.

Comment: @Toader: I understand the difficulty in explaining there. I was just trying to point out that there really was no difference in the functionality of the two files, but that the formatting was different. Again, it was simply personal preference.

Comment: okay thanks for that. 
i've chosen your soloution joseph since i've got more stuff in my common.php file, meaning i need the <?php - tags. 
thanks to both of you

Answer (score 12):

A very easy solution to this problem is to do this.

```
<ul>
  <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'index.php'){echo 'current'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'portfolio.php'){echo 'current'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'services.php'){echo 'current'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
  <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'contact.php'){echo 'current'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'links.php'){echo 'current'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="links.php">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

Which will output

```
<ul>
  <li class="current"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="services.php">Services</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="links.php">Links</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to put your `$page = 'one';` above the require_once.. otherwise I don't understand the question.

Comment: Hi!
There is no difference if I put $page before or after require_once.
It still prints the same thing:

<div id="nav">
            <ul>
               <li><a <? if($page == 'one'): ?> class="active"<? endif ?> href="index.php">Tab1</a>/</li>
               <li><a href="two.php">Tab2</a></li>
               <li><a href="three.php">Tab3</a></li>
           </ul>
        </div>

Comment: PHP gets not parsed in heredoc strings.

Comment: Ah wait I overlooked something. You have your entire code inside an `<<<EOD` block. The PHP code you have inside there won't get parsed. Try removing the first 2 and the last 2 lines in your common.php file. (so you only have the HTML left).

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you create a function or class for this navigation and put there active page as a parameter? This way you'd call it as, for example:

```
$navigation = new Navigation( 1 );
```

or

```
$navigation = navigation( 1 );
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but none of these answers are very good (sry ppl)

The BEST way to do it (without writing out convoluted classes) is to compare the current $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to the href of the link. You're almost there.

Try this. (Taken from http://ma.tt/scripts/intellimenu/)

```
$nav = <<<EOD
<div id="nav">
        <ul>
           <li><a href="index.php">Tab1</a></li>
           <li><a href="two.php">Tab2</a></li>
           <li><a href="three.php">Tab3</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
EOD;

$lines = explode("\n", $nav);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    if(preg_match('/href="([^"]+)"/', $line, $url)) {
        if(substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 0, 5) == substr($url[1], 0, 5)) {
            $line = str_replace('><a', ' class="current-menu-item"><a', $line);
        }
    }
    echo $line . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `$page='one'` should occur *before* you `require_once()` not after. After is too late- the code has already been required, and `$nav` has already been defined.
2. You should use `include('header.php');` and `include('footer.php');` instead of setting a `$nav` variable early on. That increases flexibility.
3. Make more functions. Something like this really makes things easier to follow:

   ```
   function maybe($x,$y){return $x?$y:'';}
   function aclass($k){return " class=\"$k\" "; }
   ```

   then you can write your "condition" like this:

   ```
   <a href="..." <?= maybe($page=='one',aclass('active')) ?>> ....
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You could use this PHP, hope it helps.

```
<?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') == 'home' ) { ?> class="active" <?php } else { ?> <?php }?>
```

So a list would be like the below.

```
<ul>
  <li <?php if( basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') == 'home' ) { ?> class="active" <?php } else { ?> <?php }?>><a href="home"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Home</span></a></li>
  <li <?php if( basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '.php') == 'listings' ) { ?> class="active" <?php } else { ?> <?php }?>><a href="other"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i> <span>Other</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CALL common.php
<style>
    .ddsmoothmenu ul li{float: left; padding: 0 20px;}
    .ddsmoothmenu ul li a{display: block;
  padding: 40px 15px 20px 15px;
  color: #4b4b4b;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  text-align: right;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-left: 1px; color: #fff; background: #000;}
    .current .test{  background: #2767A3; color: #fff;}
</style>
<div class="span8 ddsmoothmenu">
<!-- // Dropdown Menu // -->
<ul id="dropdown-menu" class="fixed">
    <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'index.php'){echo 'current'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="index.php" class="test">Home  <i>::</i> <span>welcome</span></a></li>
    <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'about.php'){echo 'current'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="about.php" class="test">About us <i>::</i> <span>Who we are</span></a></li>
    <li class="<?php if(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']) == 'course.php'){echo 'current'; }else { echo ''; } ?>"><a href="course.php">Our Courses  <i>::</i> <span>What we do</span></a></li>
</ul><!-- end #dropdown-menu -->

</div><!-- end .span8 -->

add each page
<?php include('common.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
             <ul>

                <li><a <?php echo ($page == "yourfilename") ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> href="user.php" ><span>Article</span></a></li>
                <li><a <?php echo ($page == "yourfilename") ? "class='active'" : ""; ?> href="newarticle.php"><span>New Articles</span></a></li>

                </ul>
```

Comment: Mind editing your answer and add elaborating description to it.

Comment: If You are on news.php page means it activated the current news.php page menu

Answer (score 0):

The solution i'm using is as follows and allows you to set the active class per php page.

**Give each of your menu items a unique class, i use `.nav-x` (nav-about, here).**

`<li class="nav-item nav-about">
    <a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About</a>
</li>`

**At the top of each page (about.php here):**

```
<!-- Navbar Active Class -->
<?php $activeClass = '.nav-about > a'; ?>
```

**Elsewhere (header.php / index.php):**

```
<style>
<?php echo $activeClass; ?> {
    color: #fff !important;
}
</style>
```

Simply change the `.nav-about > a` per page, `.nav-forum > a`, for example.

**If you want different styling (colors etc) for each nav item, just attach the inline styling to that page instead of the index / header page.**

Answer (score 0):

seperate your page from nav bar.

pageOne.php:

```
$page="one";
include("navigation.php");
```

navigation.php

```
if($page=="one"){$oneIsActive = 'class="active"';}else{ $oneIsActive=""; }
if($page=="two"){$twoIsActive = 'class="active"';}else{ $twoIsActive=""; }
if($page=="three"){$threeIsActive = 'class="active"';}else{ $threeIsActive=""; }

<ul class="nav">
  <li <?php echo $oneIsActive; ?>><a href="pageOne.php">One</a></li>
  <li <?php echo $twoIsActive; ?>><a href="pageTwo.php"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
  <li <?php echo $threeIsActive; ?>><a href="pageThree.php"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

I found that I could also set the title of my pages with this method as well.

```
 $page="one";
 $title="This is page one."
 include("navigation.php");
```

and just grab the $title var and put it in between the "title" tags. Though I am sending it to my header page above my nav bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="store/index" <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/store/index') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?> > Link </a>
<a href="account/referral" <?php if($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] == '/account/referral') { ?>class="active"<?php } ?> > Link </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP code

```
      <?php 
  function activeClass($chkStr){
     // echo "testing data";
     // echo strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
     if($chkStr=="home" && strlen($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])<3){
        return "active";
     }
     
     if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $chkStr)!==false){
        return "active";
     }
     else{
        return "";
     }

  }

  ?>
```

HTML CODE :

```
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
                       <li class="nav-item <?php echo activeClass("home"); ?>">
                          <a class="nav-link txt" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-item  <?php echo activeClass("about-us.php"); ?>">
                          <a class="nav-link txt" href="about-us.php">About Us</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-item  <?php echo activeClass("services.php"); ?>">
                          <a class="nav-link txt" href="services.php">Services</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-item  <?php echo activeClass("our-team.php"); ?>">
                          <a class="nav-link txt" href="our-team.php">Our team</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-item  <?php echo activeClass("media-awards.php"); ?>">
                          <a class="nav-link txt" href="media-awards.php">Media & Awards</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-item  <?php echo activeClass("blog.php"); ?>">
                          <a class="nav-link txt" href="blog.php">Blog</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-item  <?php echo activeClass("contact-us.php"); ?>">
                          <a class="nav-link txt" href="contact-us.php">Contact Us</a>
                       </li>

                    </ul>
```