# Change css class with php multi pages

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a multiple pages website where I wan't to change some css stuffs.
So my index.php?p=page points to various pages but on every page I also want to adjust some css like the color of the currently active menu item(li) etc.

What is the best way to achieve this? Should i just make a php var on each page?

Comment: Just put the CSS in a pair of `<style>` tags on each individual page. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: possible duplicate of [How add class='active' to html menu with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913415/how-add-class-active-to-html-menu-with-php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to handle this is to put a class on the BODY tag for each page, then make different subclasses for the stuff that changes. This way you don't need to feed in any variables from PHP. It's all done via CSS.

```
<body class="pageOne">
```

CSS:

```
.pageOne h1 {
    color:#ff0000
}

.pageTwo h1 {
    color:#000000
}
```

Comment: the content on each page is very basic so I am including it in the body element Can I still change the body class easily ?

Comment: I like to do `<html class="<?php echo $pageClass ?>">` where `$pageClass` is populated beforehand or being drawn from the database along with the page. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should have the CSS on an external file, and link it using a `<link>` tag, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_stylesheet.css">
```