# PHP - add class to anchor in loop

Tags: php, html, image, wordpress, anchor

I need to add a class of 'project-img' to each anchor on this page: http://petekingston.com/portfolio/test/

My code (PHP loop) for this atm is:

```
<div id="container">
<?php foreach (simple_portfolio_media() as $media_item): ?>
    <div class="box lightGrey masonry masonry-brick">
        <?php   
            $class = ('') ? 'class="project-img"' : '';
            switch ($media_item['type']):
                case 'image':
                    $src = wp_get_attachment_image_src($media_item['value'], 'full');
                    echo "<a $class href=\"$src[0]\">" . wp_get_attachment_image($media_item['value']) . "</a>";
                    break;
                case 'youtube':
                    echo "<p>";
                    echo "<object width=\"480\" height=\"385\">";
                    echo "  <param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.youtube.com/" . $media_item['value'] . "&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1\"/>";
                    echo "  <param name=\"allowFullScreen\" value=\"true\"/>";
                    echo "  <param name=\"allowscriptaccess\" value=\"always\"/>";
                    echo "  <embed src=\"http://www.youtube.com/v/" . $media_item['value'] . "&amp;hl=en_US&amp;fs=1\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowscriptaccess=\"always\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"480\" height=\"385\"/>";
                    echo "</object>";
                    echo "</p>";
                    break;
                case 'snippet':
                    echo $media_item['value'];
                    break;
            endswitch;
        ?>
    </div><!-- END box -->
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div><!-- END container -->
```

However, it is not adding the class to the anchors. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Pete

Comment: What is $class = ('') ? 'class="project-img"' : ''; ? It is checking what empty string?

Comment: I am unfortunately no good with PHP and have tried to incorporate code from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913415/how-add-class-active-to-html-menu-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not using your  tag with the same class anywhere else, only in case 'image', why do you need a condition to $class variable? Even more, why do you need declaration 'class="project-img"' to the variable? I would be using this way:

```
 $class = 'project-img';
 ...
 echo "<a class='$class' href=\"$src[0]\">" ...
```

Comment: Fantastic, the class is so I can target it with fancybox and style it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison operator in your ternary test is wrong : use `==` instead of `=`.

```
$class = ($class == ('')) ? 'class="project-img"' : '';
```

I'm not sure of what you mean by `('')` by the way!

Comment: Yeah, I have changed that with @Royal_BG 's code. I know next to nothing about PHP so none of this code is what I have written. Thank you for the quick response though. (Apologies for not explaining the problem more accurately)