# twitter bootsrap 3 + Expressjs+Jade, navbar active.state not changing

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap-3, pug

i'm mixinq with nodejs,

i'm using the same navbar as [here](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/justified-nav/)

the navbar 'buttons' are not chnging, when i use the li.active for test it is working, but how to change states to active when i press other button ( other becoma active 'and inactivate the previous' ?

also, i have added a script ( i load after bootsrap.js... ) but it is not working....

```
$('.nav li').click(function(e) {

        $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

could You help me please to figure what is happening ?

Comment: All you need inside the click call back is this `$('.nav li').removeClass('active'); $(this).addClass('active');e.preventDefault();`

Comment: where i need to add this code ? the code i mentionned is in external file.js, i'm loading it in the index file ( template.jade )... or do i need to edit the bootsrtap or jquery.js ?

Comment: Share your HTML/jade markup

Comment: thank You Dear Maverick : here is the Jade ...script(src='javascripts/actlink.js')

  body
  .container
    h3.text-muted test 
        |         
        nav
          ul.nav.nav-justified
            li.active
              a(href='/') Home
            |             
            li
              a(href='/blog') blog
            |             
            li
              a(href='/links') use
            |             
            li
              a(href='/contact') contact
    block content
    block foot

Comment: i think i need something like this to make it work but i tried this example and i did not ... : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514717/bootstrap-navbar-active-state-not-working