# Bootstrap menu oppened link background color with class="nav navbar-nav"

Tags: html, css, menu, bootstrap-modal

How to change color of oppened link in bootstrap menu like on picture. It work on mouse over and after click change to default color of menu.
  i need like on picture.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="navbar-left">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Патници", "Index", "patnici")</li>
            <li >@Html.ActionLink("Помош", "Contact", "Home")</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.navbar-nav > li > a {
      padding-top: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 10px;
      line-height: 20px;
    }
```

[Menu-Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqREO.png)

Answer (score 0):

need to set active class. See the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514717/bootstrap-navbar-active-state-not-working)

Comment: where is the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Below code might help , change the color accordingly of your choice below

```
    .navbar-nav li a {
        background:#C60;
        color:#FFFFFF;
        text-decoration:none;
        display: block;
    }

    .navbar-nav li a:visited  {
        background:yellow;
        color:#F00;
        text-decoration:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help.
Create a css class "active" and set a background-color.

```
$(function() {
   $("li").click(function() {
      // remove existing class
      $("li").removeClass("active");
      // add class to the one we clicked
      $(this).addClass("active");
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```