# Bootstrap 3, change li.active for nav

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So, I'm playing around with Bootstrap, I'm a total noob. At any rate, to change the nav-brand, I had to use:

```
.navbar-brand {
   color: #da212f!important;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #DDD;
}
```

That said, I had to use the !important declaration to get the text color to change. Is there a way around that (I'm just curious).

The problem is, I'm trying to change the background color and the font color for the li.active in the nav bar.

**Here is the HTML**

```
<!-- Start Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Mr. Robot</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="computers.html">Hardware</a></li>
        <li><a href="robots.html">Robots</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

For the life of me, I can't get the background color to change and I'd like to know how to change the font color as well.

Here was the CSS Options I've tried:

**Option 1**

```
li.active {
   background-color: #da212f!important;
   color: #fff!important;
}
```

**Option 2**

```
.navbar-nav > li.active {
       background-color: #da212f!important;
       color: #fff!important;
    }
```

I've tried both, with and without the !important declaration. So, if someone could help me and point me in the right direction, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Overall, you don't want to use `!important`?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514717/bootstrap-navbar-active-state-not-working

Comment: I'm not using or wanting to use jquery to change it. I'm wanting to use CSS. It's not a duplicate, I read that one first. He wanted to change just the link text. Either way I tried that option too. @Swellar, if possible, I'd prefer to not use !important unless required. Either way, for the li.active, !important is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the logo brand you can add an id to the `navbar-brand` element and that will give it higher [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

```
#myBrand {
  color: #da212f;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #DDD;
}
```

For the active link you use the following

```
.nav.navbar-nav > li.active a{
  background: none;     
  background-color: #da212f;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```css
#myBrand {
  color: #da212f;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #DDD;
}

.nav.navbar-nav > li.active a{
  background: none;     
  background-color: #da212f;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a id="myBrand" class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Mr. Robot</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Robots</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.navbar-header > .navbar-brand {
   color: #da212f;
   text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #DDD;
}
```

As there is a div with class="navbar-header" and then in that div you can find an anchor tag with calss = "navbar-brand" where you have done branding as "Mr. Robot".

For active li tag:

```
.nav.navbar-nav > li.active a{   
  background-color: #da212f;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Adding a screenshot for your reference.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To achieve expected result, use below `CSS`

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:active{
   background-color: #da212f;
   color: #fff;
}
```

```css
.navbar-brand {
  color: #da212f!important;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #DDD;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:active {
  background-color: #da212f;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- Start Navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Mr. Robot</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Hardware</a></li>
        <li><a href="robots.html">Robots</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Joe's answer worked perfectly. I do appreciate the time and effort you put into trying to help me.