# Active link in navbar not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

So, i want to make an active links in navbar, but it's working only on "Pocetna" page, but not on others...this is what i've done:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <a href="#"><li class="active">Pocetna</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Forum</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Galerija</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>Donacije</li></a>
        <a href="#"><li>O nama</li></a>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and this is in my style.css :

```
nav li.active{
    color: #CCCCCC;
}
```

I'm using bootstrap...

Comment: You need the class `active` to move to the relevant `li` for each page. You can do it manually or programmatically.

Comment: @ovokuro any examples?

Comment: The simplest solution would be to just move the `class="active"` attribute to the relevant `li` depending what page you are on.

Comment: Since you are using Bootstrap, check in the dev tools if the `active` class changes within the `<li>` elements, and I don't see any other Bootstrap classes, or move the class depending on what page you are on

Comment: First correct your html markup. Place `a` tag inside `li` tag. May be this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514717/bootstrap-navbar-active-state-not-working

Answer (score 1):

Did you create a HTML-file for each of your navlinks?

If you did, please do the following:

**1. Go to your 'Forum' HTML index file, and change the Navbar to:**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href="#"><li>Pocetna</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="active">Forum</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Galerija</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Donacije</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>O nama</li></a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

**2. Then go to your 'Galerija' HTML index file, and change the Navbar to:**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <a href="#"><li>Pocetna</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Forum</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li class="active">Galerija</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>Donacije</li></a>
    <a href="#"><li>O nama</li></a>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Do you understand where I'm going with this? You only need to add the `class="active"` to your *active* HTML index file.

Don't touch the CSS unless you wish to change the active color of your Navbar links.