# Active class is not being added to navbar-nav nav-item

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

When a link is clicked on, the active class should be added to the menu that was clicked on so that it's highlighted. I'm not able to get this behaviour, so when i click on any link only the first one remains highlighted. Must be missing something and i can't pin point it. Here's my code

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
<li class="nav-item active">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/"><i class="fa fa-home" aria-hidden="true"></i>Home</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="about">About</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That's a Javascript  /Jquery issue....where is yours? Have you llinked it in?

Comment: I have included the bootstrap.js file under my jquery.js file at the bottom of my page

Comment: Then you need to demo it *not* happening.

Comment: no console errors? And can you provide a working snippet to us see the error too?

Answer (score 1):

I edited this because I found a similar post with a working answer on it.

Follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514717/bootstrap-navbar-active-state-not-working). It has to deal with bootstrap 3 but it works with 4 too.

Also read and make sure you use correctly this [link](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/).

First of all make sure you have correctly included the stylesheet and script of bootstrap:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

`<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Secondly, make sure that the active class is not overrided by the `nav-link` or `fa` class that you are using inside the `<li></li>` element.

Try to add a new list item to your code and see if it works:

`<li class="active"><a href="https://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a></li>`

If it is not try to create a new class that contains the stylesheet of the active class and use !important. Then add it to your element:

i.e. `.myclass{ padding-top: 100px !important; }`

If any of the above works make sure that when you are Styling your html/php file you are always Inspecting your project through your browser. There you can add or remove css formats and see the exact style of your element.

Comment: Also make sure that your libraries, scripts and stylesheets are on the top of your html/php file.

Comment: I think this question is tagged with `bootstrap-4`. Have you missed that?

Comment: Thank you for the notice. Yes i missed that.

Comment: So, now that you are aware of it you don't feel any need to edit your post, do you??

Comment: @WebDevBooster spent your time on StackOverflow so you can help others or learn something from them. If you are not willing to provide an answer/comment to a post that fits in as a solution or guides the one that asked it, then get out of here. You did 4 comments about criticizing other people's comment/answer. Improve your self first. This is not facebook.

Answer (score 1):

May be your page is being reloaded after clicking on the link or redirecting to other link. The redirection will bring your link to initial state.
Otherwise there may be some javascript issue with your code.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question. Do not put comments in the Answer section. Please delete this.

Comment: @Rob It's impossible to post comments with a reputation score less than 50. There seem to be quite a few of you mods you don't know this simple fact...

Comment: @WebDevBooster We know this simple fact and it is done that way for a reason that people like you don't seem to be aware of.

Comment: @Rob OK, what's the point of your comment then?? That user has a reputation score of 1. I had also got such comments when my rep. score was under 50.

Comment: To let the poster know 1) why his comment will soon be deleted and 2) a hint that he should have paid attention when he signed up for SO when he was told he should "Take the Tour" and read the Help Center. Apparently you still haven't.

Comment: @Rob This is what you are saying NOW and that would have been helpful to the user. But definitely NOT your first comment. That one is just pointless and annoying.