# "Active" class not working in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

There is another question on this site that is the similar to this one, but unfortunately after trying all of the suggestions following that question, I still haven't found a solution.

My Navbar is looking very basic at this point:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand"<%= link_to 'GoChat', root_path %></a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %></li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <%= link_to 'View Comments', comments_path %></li>
        <li class="nav item">
            <%= link_to 'Profile', user_path(current_user) %></li>
     </ul>     
  </div>
</nav>
```

Following the advice given on the question [Bootstrap navbar Active State not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514717/bootstrap-navbar-active-state-not-working), I tried adding the following code to my application js file, but this didn't work. I also tried using html links instead of the embedded Ruby links I'm currently using.

```
$(".nav-item").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

I also tried using the "nav a" tag in the jquery code, and even the "li" tag too but this didn't work.

I'm not using the Bootstrap CDN - I downloaded the compressed and minified files to my app. I tried with the CDN also but to no effect.
Other than that, I think the only thing to mention is that the following code is used in my application js:

```
//= require rails-ujs

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

and in application css:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require rails_bootstrap_forms
```

I don't have any idea of what to try next so I would really appreciate some help on this one, thanks :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What is happening? What did you expect would happen?

Comment: The active class renders the button a different shade to indicate that it is the one in use.

Comment: @Robert , simple question have you added bootstrap cdn js/css into header? Also i dont see `$(".nav-link")` - `.nav-link` anywhere in your **HTML**.

Comment: Sorry, it seems I missed this - I'm not using the cdn, I downloaded the compressed and minified files to my app. But I did try usibg the cdn to see if it made any difference - which it didn't.

Answer (score 0):

So first i include the [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/) cdn.

After your question has been edited, i think you are missing the `jQuery` link (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins).

```
  <!--jQuery -->
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

> This is just an example , as your js is targeting HTML class you dont have.

```js
$(".nav-item").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href= "/stylesheets/styles.css" />

<!--jQuery -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
<script src="/bootstrap/js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>



<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand"<%= link_to 'GoChat', root_path %></a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %></li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
            <%= link_to 'View Comments', comments_path %></li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <%= link_to 'Profile', user_path(current_user) %></li>
     </ul>     
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is all given in the question I referred to above. I have tried all the different tags in the Jquery code but to the same result.

Comment: Its really weird, this should work, i changed my code, in ur `li` yout last class misses an `-` , also sorry for asking but since i cant see all your code , are you also including jQuery? as i did above on `<!--jQuery -->`

Comment: I'm not using the CDN so I haven't done this in the same way. I've just required jquery in the js file. If there's anything else I need to do then I don't know about this

Comment: does your console show any errors ? "I've just required jquery in the js file" meaning you downloaded jQuery and added into js directory which get included to the header? `you cant download jQuery and include it into a file` else Then you are on the right track , and also then im not sure whats wrong to be honest. If you `view page source` and see the linked style tags and script tags, your code should work. (update this line `$(this).addClass("active");` )

Comment: I haven't downloaded jQuery at any point - I just have the jquery-rails gem in my app. Bootstrap only requires you to download javascript and css files so I suppose I assumed that jquery was somewhere in that. Does any action need to be taken with jquery to make Bootstrap fully function?

Comment: im a no-go on ruby/ruby-on-rails , but if your source code shows jQuery then i dont know whats wrong, but yess like can see above, you need jQuery to implement this function. You wil see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#template) its including jQuery cdn.

Answer (score 0):

Please excuse the long answer in advance :)

I have 2 syntactical suggestions:

---

#### 1: `<a>` i.e. `link_to` syntax

It looks like in line 4 you have an error in your `erb` syntax:

**Problem**:

- This **will not work** in your view:

  `<a class="navbar-brand"<%= link_to 'GoChat', root_path %></a>`
- You need to close your `<a>` tag i.e:

  `<a class="navbar-brand"><%= link_to 'GoChat', root_path %></a>`
- There's a problem with this. I doubt you want an anchor tag within an anchor tag, but with the given syntax, your code will compile to this:

  `<a class="navbar-brand"><a href="/your_root_path">GoChat</a></a>`

**Solution**:

- In Rails, you can achieve what you want here with this:

  `<%= link_to 'GoChat', root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>`
- This will compile to:

  `<a href="/your_root_path" class="navbar-brand">GoChat</a>`

---

#### 2: `<li>` syntax

**Problem:**

- Your 3rd `<li>` is missing a hyphen in the class name.

**Solution:**

- I think you want:

  `<li class="nav-item">`

---

---

---

#### Apropos your question

I think the effect you are trying to achieve can be demonstrated in the snippet below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-item a").click(function() {
    $('.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Go Chat</a>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#">New Comment</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a href="#">View Comments</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a href="#">Show Profile</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

---

- However, from looking at your code it seems you are trying to get an active class based on a current route. You can't easily or practically achieve this with JQuery event handlers since the page route will be changed and a new page will be loaded when clicking on a link.

---

#### Proposed Solution

I would forget the JQuery altogether in this example. Try applying the `active` class conditionally based on the current route using `erb` like so:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <%= link_to 'GoChat', root_path, class: "navbar-brand" %>
    </div>

    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(new_comment_path) %>">
        <%= link_to 'New Comment', new_comment_path %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(comments_path) %>">
        <%= link_to 'View Comments', comments_path %>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item <%= 'active' if current_page?(user_path(current_user)) %>">
        <%= link_to 'Profile', user_path(current_user) %>
      </li>
    </ul>    
  </div>
</nav>
```

---

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the solution. I'm a bit surprised that Navbars in Bootstrap don't offer this functionality, it seems like quite an obvious requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Some time bootstrap doesn't work when our browser is not working, so check it first and add proper online links then execute.
So I write some code of 'Active' class bootstrap, just try it.It may help you to solve your problem.Thank you!

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">`enter code here`
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active" ><a href="wordpress.com" target="blank">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```