# Set Boostrap navigation item "active" with Sails.js

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sails.js

Boostrap makes it easy to set a navigation item "active" so that users know which page they're on ([more info](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/#nav)). How do I dynamically set/remove the "active" CSS class from the navigation item in Sails.js?

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
  <li class="nav-item active" id="map-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/">Map</a>
  </li>  
  <li class="nav-item active" id="faq-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item active" id="contact-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

There [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514717/bootstrap-navbar-active-state-not-working) multiple solutions online that use plain JavaScript or AJAX but I don't know how I can imoplement that in Sails.js.

I have a layout.ejs file which defines the general layout of every page, and then I have ejs pages for Map, FAQ and contact. Ideally, it would be best to only change a single part of the code in case I decide to add more pages later on.

Answer (score 0):

For a purely Sails JS solution you can do the following
use `req.path`, reference [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-path), to get the request URL and pass it into your view. So for example the URL is **www.sailsapp.com/faq** using `let a = req.path` in the controller will give you variable **a** with value of '**/faq**'. Then in your view you can use an if like

```
<li class="nav-item active" id="faq-item">
<a class="nav-link <% if (a == '/faq') {%> active <%}%>" href="/faq">FAQ</a>
</li>
```

You can use this logic for any of the links you wish to.