# bootstrap 4 .active class not changing on click

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using bootstrap v4.3.1 in a ASP.NET MVC core website. I have a navbar where I have the .active class on the a tag on the first li:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-toggleable-md navbar-dark bg-navbar fixed-top mb-3">
  <div class="container">
    <a
      class="navbar-brand"
      asp-area=""
      asp-controller="Home"
      asp-action="Index"
    >
      <img id="nav-logo" src="~/Images/LOGO's.png" alt="G&Z Installation" />
    </a>
    <button
      class="navbar-toggler"
      type="button"
      data-toggle="collapse"
      data-target=".navbar-collapse"
      aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
      aria-expanded="false"
      aria-label="Toggle navigation"
    >
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-md-inline-flex flex-md-row-reverse">
      <ul class="nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link active text-light nav-text"
            asp-area=""
            asp-controller="Home"
            asp-action="Index"
          >
            Home
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link text-light nav-text"
            asp-area=""
            asp-controller="Home"
            asp-action="SolarPanels"
          >
            Zonnepanelen
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link text-light nav-text"
            asp-area=""
            asp-controller="Home"
            asp-action="AircoAndHeatPump"
          >
            Airco & Warmtepomp
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link text-light nav-text"
            asp-area=""
            asp-controller="Home"
            asp-action="Contact"
          >
            Contact
          </a>
        </li>
        @*
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a
            class="nav-link text-light"
            asp-area=""
            asp-controller="Home"
            asp-action="Privacy"
          >
            Privacy
          </a>
        </li>
        *@
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>;
```

I added this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a.nav-link.text-light.nav-text").on("click", function () {
    $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

The active class is not changing after clicking an other li item. It is staying on the first li item.
Bootstrap is loaded in the head of the layout page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
```

And the scripts are loaded at the bottom of the layout page:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

EDIT:
When I look at the elements in the browser, I can see the active class been deleted from the first li item when I click the second, but then I see it automatically been added to the first li item again.. As if it refreshes or something..
If I edit the js-code (and the .active class on the li item instead of the a tag), it works, but then the navigation is not working anymore.. This is because of the "e.preventDefault()" where the "e" is for the a tag.. Whitout it will not work for the .active class..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.nav li a').click(function (e) {

    $('.nav li.active').removeClass('active');

    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.addClass('active');
    e.preventDefault();
});});
```

It's been a while since I worked with bootstrap and asp.net mvc. I'm not seeing what I do wrong. Any tips?

Comment: Your script path's are wrong, Can you add it as a Snippet

Comment: working fine https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/ek8qxwm3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution thanks to [the answer of Jon here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24514717/bootstrap-navbar-active-state-not-working) !!! :)
I changed the JS code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li.active').removeClass('active');
  $('a[href="' + location.pathname + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active'); 
});
```

Now it works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.I take active class in css just for demo purpose you can use your own class.Thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a.nav-link").on("click", function () {
$("a.nav-link").each(function(i,o)
{
$(this).removeClass("active");
});
    $(this).addClass("active");
})
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: #666;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-toggleable-md navbar-dark bg-navbar fixed-top mb-3">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">
                <img id="nav-logo" src="~/Images/LOGO's.png" alt="G&Z Installation" />
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-md-inline-flex flex-md-row-reverse">
                <ul class="nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active text-light nav-text" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light nav-text" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SolarPanels">Zonnepanelen</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light nav-text" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="AircoAndHeatPump">Airco & Warmtepomp</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-light nav-text" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                    @*<li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                        </li>*@
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This is not changing anything in my case.. I think you are using bootstrap v3 instead of v4. I've added a small text above. I can see the active class been removed, but then it automatically comes back to the first li item..