# How would I go about using PHP to define the "active" tab of a navigation bar when using a header.php page

Tags: php, html, css, header, navigation

I'm trying do a navigation bar that has a "current" class to whichever page we're on. But the navigation bar is on a header.php page and I use an include tag to bind pages with the header.

How would I go about this? 
I assumed I would use something similar to;

```
if(strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'index') !== false){;
```

But I'm not confident enough to tackle this on my own.

https://jsfiddle.net/zo5oy46q/

Thankyou!

Comment: Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913415/how-add-class-active-to-html-menu-with-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of every page create a variable called for example `$page_name`, and assign a name to each page.

Then in every tab add the `current` class in base of the page's name.

Example:

```
<a href="/home" class="<?php echo $page_name == 'home' ? 'current' : '' ?>"></a>
<a href="/contact" class="<?php echo $page_name == 'contact' ? 'current' : '' ?>"></a>
```