# How to active sidebar menu using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to set a class on the active menu item using jQuery for sidebar menu. I don't have any idea how to use active class using jQuery. Here's my sidebar menu code:

```
<div class="leftside-navigation">
  <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
    <li>
      <a class="mnb active" href="index.php">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu">
      <a href="javascript:;">
        <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
        <span>Applied Loan</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a class="mnb" href="loan_edu.php">Education</a></li>
        <li><a class="mnb" href="loan_med.php">Medical</a></li>
        <li><a class="mnb" href="loan_othr.php">Other</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu">
      <a href="javascript:;">
        <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
        <span>Approved Loan</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="aprove_edu.php">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="aprove_med.php">Medical</a></li>
        <li><a href="aprove_othr.php">Other</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you've got an example how to set it up with jQuery in previous answers. If you need to check it with PHP, I think that this might help you.

1) Declare a variable in your pages (e.g: aboutus.php, cotactus.php) just before including header.php or menu.php whichever file your navigation markup is in.

```
 <?php
 $page = 'aboutus';
 include('header.php');
 ?>
```

2) Now in your header.php, you read the value of this variable to determine which is the page being viewed and accordingly you assign a different/additional CSS style to its navigational link.

```
   <ul class="mainmenu" >
      <li class="menuitem <?php if($page=='aboutus'){echo 'active';}?>" >
        <a href="aboutus.php"><span>About Us</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem <?php if($page=='contactus'){echo 'active';}?>" >
        <a href="contactus.php"><span>Contact Us</span></a>
      </li>  
   </ul>
```

Hope it helps…

Answer (score 0):

For each element of your links, add event listener for `click`, remove all the active classes, and set the current `a` to active :

```js
$('a').click(function(){
  $('a.active').each(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftside-navigation">
  <ul class="sidebar-menu" id="nav-accordion">
    <li>
      <a class="mnb active" href="index.php">
        <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
        <span>Dashboard</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu">
      <a href="javascript:;">
        <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
        <span>Applied Loan</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a class="mnb" href="loan_edu.php">Education</a></li>
        <li><a class="mnb" href="loan_med.php">Medical</a></li>
        <li><a class="mnb" href="loan_othr.php">Other</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="sub-menu">
      <a href="javascript:;">
        <i class="fa fa-book"></i>
        <span>Approved Loan</span>
      </a>
      <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="aprove_edu.php">Education</a></li>
        <li><a href="aprove_med.php">Medical</a></li>
        <li><a href="aprove_othr.php">Other</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this link - `https://codepen.io/arjunamgain/pen/lGALt`

This is the jQuery part:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul li a').click(function(){
    $('li a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: This sidebar separated php file and include each page using php include(). I put your script each page but not working.

Comment: I don't know if I understand you correct but check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913415/how-add-class-active-to-html-menu-with-php

Answer (score 0):

by using `jquery`:

```
var url =window.location;
$('#leftside-navigation a[href="' + url + '"]').addClass('active')
```