# Move to Another Page Without Reload and Give Active Class To The Current Active Page Loaded

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have `index.php`, `page1.php`, `page2.php`, `page3.php` and I wanted to load their content in the `index.php` page within the div with `#output` but I don't want them to reload/refresh every time the navbar is clicked. Also, I want the active page has the `active` class in the active `<li>`.

> index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar bg-light">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Main</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="page1.php">Page 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="page2.php">Page 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="page3.php">Page 3</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<br>

<div class="container-fluid" id="output">
  THE CONTENT FROM ANOTHER PAGE THAT'LL LOAD HERE
</div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Comment: Either you move all the php pages content onto a single page (`index.php`) and show/hide content (SPA). Or you implement ajax.

Comment: @marblewraith The contents are too heavy to do like that, that's why....

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913415/how-add-class-active-to-html-menu-with-php

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example:

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up" id="friends">
    <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843293/" data-target="#contacts" class="media_node active span" id="contacts_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Contacts </a></li>
    <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843301/" data-target="#friends_list" class="media_node span" id="friends_list_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip"> Friends list</a></li>
    <li><a href="/gh/gist/response.html/3843306/" data-target="#awaiting_request" class="media_node span" id="awaiting_request_tab" data-toggle="tabajax" rel="tooltip">Awaiting request</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="contacts">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="friends_list">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane  urlbox span8" id="awaiting_request">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BoWw/77dyfbwd/

You can adjust this to what you posted.